# Your project has not configured Dynamic Links. React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

While creating short dynamic link in my React Native app i am facing error "Your project has not configured Dynamic Links" but when i create normal/long dynamic link it is working fine.Below is my code for creating short dynamic links and yes i have already setup Dynamic Links domain on firebase console.

```
 var getDynamicLink =  firebase.dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(
            {
                domainUriPrefix: 'https://app.page.link',
                link:`https://www.app.referrals?invitedBy=${SENDER_UID}`,
                android: {
                    packageName: "com.abc.xyz",
                },
              ios: {
                appStoreId: '123456789',
                bundleId: "com.abc.xyz",
              },
            },
            dynamicLinks.ShortLinkType.UNGUESSABLE,
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has encountered this problem, it may be due to:

1 - After completing the dynamic link installation, you may not have downloaded the current version of the google_services.json file and replaced it with the google_services.json in the android file.
2 - You may not have added the necessary filter to the Android_manifest.xml file. ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#add-an-intent-filter-for-deep-links )

If you are sure that you have done these steps correctly and the problem still persists, I suggest you send a request to the url below.

> ```
> POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=api_key
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> {
>   "dynamicLinkInfo": {
>     "domainUriPrefix": "https://example.page.link",
>     "link": "https://www.example.com/",
>     "androidInfo": {
>       "androidPackageName": "com.example.android"
>     },
>     "iosInfo": {
>       "iosBundleId": "com.example.ios"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

for api_key : **firebase -> project settings -> Web API** Key or
You can reach it via **google_services.json -> api_key -> current_key**.

If this request provides correct feedback, there is definitely something wrong with your firebase installation. Try the installation again step by step.